# I have enabled a smart contract with transferfrom - Getting GAS error

Tags: dapps, transferfrom

[image: Gas error when trying to do transferfrom]

Any advice on where to start looking for my error?

Comment: Can you share your smart contract's code inside your question body?

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason is that you are not approved to spend tokens for the `from` address.

This means the `from` address should approve you to spend the tokens and then only you can use the `transferFrom` function.

Add more details or paste the etherscan link for the contract, so that we can have a look.